# About or & and operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

How  the logical operators i.e;(or, and) works on the strings or numbers?

Example:

```
print(2 or 3)--> o/p: 2
print('two' or 'three')--> o/p: 'two'
```

I want to know how internally it works and reason behind the output's

Comment: What exactly is your question? Can you clarify what exactly you want to know?

Comment: And why the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

`or` will "choose" the first thing if it is not `False`, else the second one:

```
print(2 or 3)             # non-0 numbers are True
print('two' or 'three')   # non empty strings are True
print(0 or 3)             # 0 is False
print('' or 'three')      # empty string is False
```

Output:

```
2
two
3
three
```

Certain "things" are considered `False`.

See [and,or,not](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) and [Logical comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while
>   condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below.
>
> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines
>   either a **bool**() method that returns False or a **len**() method
>   that returns zero, when called with the object. [1] Here are most of
>   the built-in objects considered false:
>
> - constants defined to be false: None and False.
> - zero of any numeric type: 0, 0.0, 0j, Decimal(0), Fraction(0, 1)
> - empty sequences and collections: '', (), [], {}, set(), range(0)